# How to make an ArrayAdapter in a class that extends fragment?

Tags: android, listview

My code:

```
public class NewsFeedActivity extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_feed, container, false);
        return view;

    }
    ListView l;
    String[] names={"Schuyler", "Faraz"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        l= (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, names);//Here is the problem

    }

}
```

I wish to use a `Listview` with this Fragment but I don't know how to do so. In a normal class that extends Activity one would use `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, bla, bla)` but I can not do that in a class that extends Fragment. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActivity` instead of `this`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, names);
```

`public final Activity getActivity ()`

```
Added in API level 11
Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
public class NewsFeedActivity extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_feed, container, false);
        l= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, names);
        l.setAdapter(ad);
        return view;
    }
    private ListView l;
    private String[] names={"Schuyler", "Faraz"};


}
```